# Mysql finding date between two columns [Start_Date] and [End_date]

Tags: mysql

my table is like this

```
|id|start_time|end_time|start_date|end_date  |
|01| 10:00Am  | 10:PM  |2014-08-19|2014-08-30|
```

i want to find my specific date between two columns start_date and end_date

```
select start_time,end_time
from table 
where 2014-08-24 <= end_date and >= start_date
```

how can i find my specific date

Comment: i want to find my own date between these two date start_date and end_date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `date` in `db` rows, try this way

```
SELECT `start_time`, `end_time`
FROM `table` 
WHERE `start_date` <= "2014-08-24" AND `end_date` >= "2014-08-24"
```

Comment: Great ! Its work like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need to use between condition:

```
select start_time,end_time
from table
where '2014-08-24' between start_date and end_date
```